# Characterizing continuity via open inverse image and sequential continuity

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Given $(X,\tau_d,d)$, $(Y,\tau_e,e)$, where $\tau_k$ is the topology metrized by metric $k$, and $f:X\to Y$, we'd like to show that

(a) $f$ is continuous (i.e. $f^{-1}(U)\in\tau_d$ for all $U\in\tau_e$) iff

(b) $f$ is sequentially continuous: for every $x\in X$ and every sequence $x_n\to x$ in metric $d$, we have $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ in metric $e$.

I've shown (a) $\Rightarrow$ (b), and am having trouble showing (b) $\Rightarrow$(a). Here's what I've got so far:

Pick $U\in \tau_e$, $y\in U$, and $x\in f^{-1}(y)$. [We know that $U\in\tau_d$ iff for every $u\in U$, there exists $V\in\tau_d$ so that $u\in V\subset U$. So we're looking for such a set $V$.]

Pick $x_n\in B(x,\frac{1}{n})$. Then $d(x_n,x)<\frac{1}{n}$ so $x_n\to x$, and by assumption of sequential continuity, $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. Since $U$ is open, there exists $\delta>0$ so that $B_e(f(x),\delta)\subset U$ (open balls are a base for the topology); fix such $\delta>0$. Then for $n\ge N$, $e(f(x_n),f(x))<\delta$, so $\{f(x_n)\}_{n\ge N}\subset B_e(f(x),\delta)$, and hence $\{x_n\}_{n\ge N}\subset f^{-1}(B_e(f(x),\delta)$.

I'm guessing that $B_d(x,\frac{1}{N})$ is our candidate for $V$, i.e. we want $B_d(x,\frac{1}{N})\subset f^{-1}(B_e(f(x),\delta)$. This is where I get stuck. If $s\in B_d(x,\frac{1}{N})$ with $s\neq x_n$ for some $n\ge N$, I'd like to say that $s$ is close enough to $x$ that $f(s)$ is not more than $\delta$ from $f(x)$, but the closeness in $Y$ is given only along the sequence $x_n$.

Is it good enough that $x_n$ was an arbitrary sequence? I'm thinking it isn't. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let it be that $f$ is **not** continuous.

Then $f^{-1}\left(U\right)\notin\tau_{d}$
for some $U\in\tau_{e}$.

Then $f^{-1}\left(U\right)$ will contain a limit point of its complement.

Let $x\in f^{-1}(U)$ be such a limitpoint of $f^{-1}(U)^c$.

So for every $n$ we can find some
$x_{n}$ with $f\left(x_{n}\right)\notin U$ and $d\left(x,x_{n}\right)<\frac{1}{n}$.

Then evidently $x_{n}\to x$, but not $f\left(x_{n}\right)\to f\left(x\right)$.

Conclusion: $f$ is **not** sequentially continuous.

Comment: Great, thanks a bunch drhab! I didn't get how to use the fact that a set is not open; now it makes great sense.

You helped me out with probability a year and a half ago when I started using this site, and here you are again! You the man

Comment: Glad to be of help. You are very welcome.